# How to apply function on variable based on consecutive values in another variable

Tags: python, dataframe, variables, iteration

I have a data frame with the image number (sliceno) and x and y coordinates (x-position and y-position, respectively). These images are taken over time and the same slice number indicates multiple coordinates recorded at the same timepoint.

I want to compare coordinates of images to the one(s) before. If the x coordinate of a subsequent image is +/-1 or equal to x coordinate of the previous image and this happens twice, i.e. there are two recordings of the same sliceno which satisfy the coordinate requirements. The same for the y coordinates.

```
import pandas as pd

print(dataframe)
x-position  y-position  radius (pixels)  r-squared of radius fitting sliceno
0          220         220           19.975                        0.987       6
1          627         220           20.062                        0.981       6
2          620         220           20.060                        0.981       6
3          220         220           19.975                        0.987       7
4          628         220           20.055                        0.980       7
```

Comment: I don't think it is entirely clear what your desired output is here. What do you want returned? Would any of the records in your example meet the criteria?

Comment: @ATK7474 I would like code to: i) compare consecutive slicenos, i.e. compare sliceno x+1 to sliceno x; and ii) apply a function to determine whether x.position and y.positions for the corresponding slice is +/-1 x.position or y.position for the previous sliceno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to break this down to make it clear what is going on, but this should give you two new columns 'x' and 'y' that contain a boolean for whether or not your criteria was met.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['x-position', 'y-position', 'radius', 'r-squared', 'sliceno'],
    index=[i for i in range(5)],
    data=[
        [220, 220, 19.975, 0.987, 6],
        [627, 220, 20.062, 0.981, 6],
        [620, 220, 20.060, 0.981, 6],
        [220, 220, 19.975, 0.987, 7],
        [628, 220, 20.055, 0.980, 7],
    ]
)
df['x_previous'] = df['x-position'].shift()
df['y_previous'] = df['y-position'].shift()
df['slice_previous'] = df['sliceno'].shift()

def check_within_one(row, axis):
    within_1 = (True if row[axis + '_previous'] - 1 <=
                        row[axis + '-position'] <=
                        row[axis + '_previous'] + 1 and
                        row['sliceno'] == row['slice_previous']
                else False)

    return within_1

df['x'] = df.apply(check_within_one, axis=1, args=('x',))
df['y'] = df.apply(check_within_one, axis=1, args=('y',))
```

You can definitely condense this down a bunch, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: This is great so far, thank you. I can use the def statement. Sorry if this wasn't clear in my question but there are multiple rows for each sliceno. So really I need each to be compared to each successive sliceno.

Comment: How would you extend the def statement to check within two please? Doesn't seem to work by adding:
`row[axis + '_previous'] - 2 <=` 
and
`row[axis + '_previous'] + 2`

Comment: @sforbes So really, you are not looking to only compare to the next row for each 'sliceno' value, but every row that shares that value? So in this example, you would want to see that the first three rows all have a 'y-position' within 1 of each other (since they are all sliceno 6)?

Comment: I want to compare all slicenos not to each other but to all the successive slicenos. So e.g. all the sliceno6s to the sliceno7s. At the moment I'm looking into constructing a dataframe which contains x-position and y-position for both slicenos of interest per row, then run the def comment for each row.

Comment: I've managed to get the data in a format that I can use the def function. Could you explain how it works to me please, so that I might edit it so that it includes +2, -2 etc?